# Tcolorbox parbox=false option breaks by height fill option

Tags: tcolorbox, bugs

Tcolorbox `parbox=false` option breaks by `height fill` option

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[most, many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
parbox=false, 
height fill % this option breaks parbox=false option
]
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, the content of a `tcolorbox` is processed into one or more internal box registers. Then, this box / these boxes are typeset with appropriate drawing code etc.

For `height fill`, there are some exceptions. Especially, the `before` code is executed before the content is processed. Unfortunately, this makes side effects possible. Here, some setting from `before` punches through.

With a patch, this can be repaired for the current example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[most, many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\tcbset{
  parskip/.style={before={\ifnum\lastnodetype=-1\relax\else\par%
      \ifvmode\edef\tcb@prevdepth{\the\glueexpr\prevdepth+\lineskip+\parskip}%
      \def\tcb@undo@before{\addvspace{-\glueexpr\tcb@prevdepth}}%
      \pagebreak[0]\fi\fi\noindent},
    after={\tcb@parfillskip@check\par}},
  noparskip/.style={before={\ifnum\lastnodetype=-1\relax\else\par%
      \ifvmode\edef\tcb@prevdepth{\the\glueexpr\prevdepth+\lineskip}%
      \def\tcb@undo@before{\addvspace{-\glueexpr\smallskipamount+\tcb@prevdepth}}%
      \pagebreak[0]\smallskip\fi\fi\noindent},
    after={\tcb@parfillskip@check\par\smallskip}},
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
parbox=false,
height fill
]
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

I will add this patch to the next `tcolorbox` version, if nothing new comes up.